# Creating a list of IDs and saving to a different API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I am linking two APIs together (customer & handset) and am using their Ids to link a customer to many handsets and save in a third 'Purchase' API. As a customer can have many handsets, I need to have a list of HandsetIds.

This is working well on the purchase form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zcmP.png), however there is a null value for my 'HandsetIds' that is preventing me from posting to the API.

In the excerpt from my newPurchasesController below, when I set a breakpoint on  _context.Purchases.Add(purchase); and enter values in the form, I get a NotSupportedException (null constant type) and that HandsetIds is an _emptyArray {int[0]}.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewPurchases(NewPurchaseDto newPurchase)
    {
        var customer = _context.Customers.Single(
      c => c.Id == newPurchase.CustomerId);

        var handsets = _context.Handsets.Where(
       m => newPurchase.HandsetIds.Contains(m.Id)).ToList();


        foreach (var handset in handsets)
        {
            var purchase = new Purchase
            {
                Customer = customer,
                Handset = handset,
                DatePurchased = DateTime.Now
            };

            _context.Purchases.Add(purchase);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I am getting the expected value for the Customer ID when I run the program.

My NewPurchaseDto:

```
 public class NewPurchaseDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<int> HandsetIds { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, here is a link to more of the related code (full controller, models etc.) in an earlier SO post I made at the beginning of this issue:
[API returning null values for linked table IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844603/api-returning-null-values-for-linked-table-ids/48845208?noredirect=1#comment84697899_48845208)

I have spent a lot of time trying to get to the bottom of this and would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Here is my view (its saving as js before html for some reason):

```js
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote modified for my own use

            var vm = {
                                movieIds: []
            };

        var customers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });


       $('#customer').typeahead({
                minLength: 2,
                highlight: true
            }, {
                name: 'customers',
                display: 'name',
                source: customers
            }).on("typeahead:select", function(e, customer) {
                vm.customerId = customer.id;
            });

            var handsets = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: '/api/handsets?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            $('#handset').typeahead({
                minLength: 2,
                highlight: true
            }, {
                name: 'handsets',
                display: 'name',
                source: handsets
            }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, handset) {
                $("#handsets").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + handset.name + "</li>");

                $("#handset").typeahead("val", "");

               

                vm.handsetIds.push(handset.id);
            });

            $("#newPurchase").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/newPurchases",
                    method: "post",
                    data: vm
                })
                    // Display toast notifications
                .done(function () {
                    toastr.success("Purchases successfully recorded");
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    toastr.error("Something wrong happened");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

```html
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Purchase Form";

}

<h2>New Purchase form</h2>


<form id="newPurchase">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        <div class="tt-container">
            <input id="customer" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Handset</label>
        <div class="tt-container">
            <input id="handset" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <ul id="handsets" class="list-group"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    

</form>
```

Comment: Please add the links you  are referring to.

Comment: When you debug, does `newPurchase.HandsetIds` have any values?

Comment: @GTown-Coder no it is null. There is a correct value for newPurchase.CustomerId

Comment: @JoeWilson Link Added, we meet again Joe - you helped me in the earlier thread. Have made some progress but not got to the bottom of it

Comment: Can you post your view?  I need to see how you're submitting values to the server.

Comment: @GTown-Coder view added

Comment: So you're trying to submit the `ul` element with an `id` of `handsets`?

Comment: @GTown-Coder yes thats it

Comment: Well in your jquery you declare the `vm` object with an array property called `movieIds`, but then you have this line: `vm.handsetIds.push(handset.id);`  you don't have a property called `handsetIds`.. try renaming `movieIds` to `handsetIds`

Comment: @GTown-Coder this has just fixed what has been two weeks of me tearing my hair out. I'd been copying and pasting a few bits from a GitHub. My God I'm an idiot but I can't thank you enough, nothing like a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: @JoeOKelly no problem.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of your `movieIds` property in the `vm` object you created in your jQuery.

First, you're getting null reference exceptions in your controller because `newPurchase.HandSetIds` is null.

In your ajax you're submitting the `vm` object to the server.

You have a line in your jQuery: `vm.handsetIds.push(handset.id);` where you're adding values to an array called `handsetIds` but you don't have a property named `handsetIds` in your `vm` object.  But, you do have an array property called `movieIds` in your `vm` object.. so just rename `movieIds` to `handsetIds` and that should resolve your issue.